# HTML fixed table (same column width) with overflow-x

Tags: html, css

I want to make a responsive table, that has the same column width for unknown number of columns. I'll be appearing/removing columns with JQuery using "display: none;" property. Each column has minimum width, or takes as much space as available, dividing it equally with other columns. When there is not enough space for all the columns, I want my table to overflow with scroll. "table-layout: fixed;" doesn't work, because it divides the space without taking min-width into consideration. JQuery solution after page load is also acceptable. There are also some strings inside that are very long that need to be word-wrapped.

Comment: Check out bootstrap table https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/  may help out

Comment: @Nithin-Techidiots I've tried doing something with it before, but it gets stretched by long text